# Why does performance monitor show more cores than I have in my DL580 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, hp-proliant, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I ran a performance monitor trace on two hp DL580 G7 servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 with 40 CPU cores. One perfmon trace showed  the server having 60 cores, and the other trace showed 64 cores. Any explanation for this? See below screenshots to illustrate.

**iLO View**

[image]

**Perfmon View (from 64-instance trace)**

[image: 64-core trace]

**Perfmon View (from 60-instance trace)**

[image: 60-core trace]

Comment: Is this Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: @ewwhite Correct, I updated the question

Comment: You need to check 'ProcessorPerformance' counter, it will show a number of instances, usually called 'PPM_Processor_X' - that's the number of logical cores available for system.

Comment: Perhaps someone set a limit on CPUs... Does "BCDEDIT /view" show any value for NUMPROC (on the 60 core server)? If so, try "BCDEDIT /deletevalue NUMPROC". More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have 40 physical CPU cores in your [HP ProLiant DL580 G7 server](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04123267). But with Hyperthreading enabled, you'll likely show 80 cores/threads to the OS. See the "*20 Threads*" per CPU in the ILO output...

Yours may be a case where Hyperthreading should be disabled. Does the OS see 80 cores? Do you have the Hyper-V role installed? (*I believe it only accesses the first 64 logical CPUs*)

Comment: I'm not the administrator of the server, more a owner/customer. I agree that perhaps Hyperthreading could be turned off, but I want to understand why perfmon is showing 60 cores on one server and 64 cores on the other (identical) server. Hyper-V role is not installed, it is a database server.

Comment: No clue... maybe it's a limitation.

Comment: Basically what our Windows SME said... I updated the question with a screenshot from the other server. Notice the number of cores is different, but the physical specs are identical.